# replace multiple values with regular Expression (Extended search mode) in notepad++

Tags: search, notepad++, mode

i was searching for some tool to help me to replace  tag with multiple values, but i quickly realized that notepad++ which i use can help me, especially with what they call it "regular Expression"

well i tried to search and learn that, but it seems i have no time, so what i need you to help me with

i need to replace many  tag with multiple values

```
<a href="wordpress_38546.html">Home</a>
<a href="reviews/">Reviews</a>
<a href="news/">News</a>
<a href="features/">Featured</a></li>
<a href="blog/">Blog</a>
<a href="contacts/">Contacts</a>
```

to make it

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Reviews</a>
<a href="#">News</a>
<a href="#">Featured</a></li>
<a href="#">Blog</a>
<a href="#">Contacts</a>
```

**The problem was** i have multiple `<a>` tag with multiple `href="" values` also inside many of the `<a>` tag there is `class=` and `id=` that i wanna keep it

**the solutions:**
Find what     :`(<a href="+.*)( )`
Replace with  :`<a href="#"`

**solutions Explanation**
the first parentheses `()` allow us to access whatever is inside the parentheses
inside it i made it seach for `<a href="` and i wanted to make to keep select what ever after the `<a href="` which is the `url` i wanna remove, so i put `+.*` to contue selecting everything after `href="` once i select the url, i wanna stop selecting so i put `space` in the second parentheses to be like that `( )` to make it stop selecting after the space that separates the elements is selected

in most causes the `<a href="url">` tag that has `class` or `id` or both, there's space between the the last Quotation mark that belongs to the `href` element and the 'class' element or any other element written after

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find what: `href=\".+\"`
- Replace with: `href="#"`

This works for the sample you have provided. It might not work if the real text is more complex.

Comment: yeah, it worked with the sample, but in an real filed, doesn't work properly :(

the problem is i have multiple '<a>' tag with multiple 'value', the '<a>' tag also have 'class' and 'id' i wanna keep it,

as they said (Necessity is the mother of invention), i will edit my question with the solution i got :)